# 1.13 - Checking if player holds item with specific name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let's say that I want to teleport a player who doesn't hold a name tag called "abc" to *X Y Z*. 

All I could come up with was `[/data get entity @p SelectedItem.tag.display.Name]` and I'm stuck here because I don't know how to compare such data (that is, if it's possible).

Comment: @Joachim For future reference, please don't try to use HTML tags unless necessary; markdown's way of new lines is a couple spaces.

Comment: @Frank Ah, okay, np. Why is that? For how they get parsed on other websites?

Comment: @Joachim As far as I know, it's just markdown's way of doing things.  Educated guess says it's easier for database storage.

Answer (score 0):

you would definitely want to work with the `/execute` command. i myself am having issues working this out considering the weird text formatting they have since converting things that normally would be simple strings into JSON with 1.13, but the gist of it is this;

`execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"<id>",display{Name:<a bunch of JSON formatting, size varies based on the item you want}}] run tp @a X Y Z`